# If I force brutal shutdown with reboot option, is there any chance Ubuntu re-open apps that were running before shutdown?

Tags: server, shutdown, reboot

I am currently using Ubuntu 16.04 on a server.
I'm wondering :
If I force brutal shutdown with reboot option while Firefox instances are still running :

```
$ sudo shutdown -r
```

How will ubuntu behave at reboot ?
Is there a chance it re-opens apps that were running before the reboot ?

I'm asking because I don't have the luxury to try and see it for myself right now. I never did it before, I need to be sure it won't re-opens apps at reboot. Does anybody knows ?

Thank you.

Comment: Not unless Ubuntu is configured to record those apps

Comment: Ubuntu closes all apps/programs when shutdown or reboot, they need to be reopen by a person after start up. I think there is start up options in ubuntu to open programs upon restart, but you have to add them in yourself.

Comment: FYI Kubuntu _does_ restore the last session by default, but that can be turned off in system settings.

Comment: thanks for all your answers and additional precisions

Answer (score 1):

Apps will not reopen after reboot. How ever you can make firefox to reopen previous session tabs on startup. To do it mark `Restore previous session` in firefox preferences.